# Stuck on continuity/derivative at origin

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let  be a positive real number. Define $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^p\sin(x) & \text{when } x \neq 0,\\ 0 & \text{when } x = 0.\end{cases}$

a) For what values of $p$ is the function continuous at the origin?

b) For what values of $p$ is the function differentiable at the origin?

c) For what values of $p$ is the derivative continuous at the origin?

HINT: The derivative rules are not sufficient here. You will actually need to use the limit definition of derivative.

I feel that with the caveat that $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$ ensures continuity at the origin for $f$, I am not sure this guarantees it for $f'(x)$. I have tried using the limit definition but am stuck. I also feel that any positive integer value for p ensures it is continuous, but rational values do not.

Comment: Did you try to use the hint?

Answer (score 1):

For continuity you can consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} |x^p\sin(x)|\leq \lim_{x\to 0} |x^p| = 0$$
since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
This means that since $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$, the $\varepsilon-\delta$-criterion for continuity is satisfied.
For differentiablity at $x=0$, let us consider the difference quotient $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^p\sin(h)} h = \lim_{h\to 0} h^{p-1}\sin(h) = 0$$, since for $p=1$, $$\lim_{h\to 0} h^0\sin(h)=\lim_{h\to 0} 1\sin(h)=0$$ and for $p>1$, $$\lim_{h\to 0} |h^{p-1}\sin(h)|\leq \lim_{h\to 0} |h^{p-1}|=0$$. Now for $0<p<1$, $$\lim_{h\to 0} h^{p-1}\sin(h)=0$$ (by applying the taylor formula to $\sin(h)$ and using continuity of normally convergent series).

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I had, but I wasn't sure if this was enough.